# Does codeigniter have an "email" keyword?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm receiving the following error:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: email

However, the error is being triggered here:

```
if(!class_exists("email"))
{
   $this->load->model("email");
}
```

So it's not an existing class, but 'email' is already being used. Is 'email' a keyword in codeigniter? If not, how can I find out what is triggering this error?

Comment: where do you load `email` model ?

Comment: At the top of a function in the controller.

Comment: it shows because CI has own email library to send emails, and may be thats the reason

Comment: as CI have email library that's why you get this error, try to give other name to your modal 
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html?highlight=email

Comment: @DevsiOdedra no its not the reason i created email model and i loaded it without any error  try to load it in class construction

Comment: Have you auto loaded this `email` model in `config/autoload.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the flaws in CI - since it uses its own superglobal object which holds any loaded library, model and third party lib.

> if you take a look at the Loader Class [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L275) you see that Codeigniter checks if the name is already used and therefore reserved.

In short:
Your problem is, you already loaded the `email` library, which means you can't use it's name anymore.

Since Codeigniter doesn't really support namespaces you have to find another technique to avoid naming collisions.
I suggest the use of a strict naming convention.

For example:

1. For any model you should use the `_model` suffix.
2. For any self made library the `_library` suffix.

In your specific case just rename your `Email` model into `Email_model`.

> For more informations how to load a model please look at their [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html).